# Should I restart my computer after Blue Screen of Death?

Tags: crash, bsod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I restart my computer after Blue Screen of Death?](https://superuser.com/questions/75624/should-i-restart-my-computer-after-blue-screen-of-death)

I just tried to [play this game](http://andrewgarrison.com/games/deflection3/), and I got the Blue Screen of Death, but my computer is still working. Should I reset my computer?

Comment: Your computer is probably thirsty and needs a drink of water? Try pouring some into one of the vents?

Comment: Duplicate of question 75624

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you really had a Blue Screen of Death, As normally the only option after that is to reboot your PC.
Is the problem repeatable? Can you post a screen shot?